# Xamarin Forms Android Custom TabbedPage ActionBar is returning null

Tags: xamarin.android, android-actionbar, xamarin.forms, android-tabs

I am using `custom TabbedPage` in my project for showing a `badges(count)` in `Tab bar`. I am using the below code for showing a `custom tab bar` but it is  always returning `null` value in `CustomTabbedPageRenderer.cs` class `OnWindowVisibilityChanged` method's `activity.ActionBar`. I have tried the many workaround like changing the `Theme` as `Theme.AppCompat.Light.DarkActionBar` and added the below line in `Window.RequestFeature(WindowFeatures.ActionBar);` **MainActivity.cs** , but unfortunately these didn't help me.

**MainActivity.cs**

```
  namespace Bakery.Droid
    {
        [Activity(Label = "Bakery.Droid", Icon = "@mipmap/icon_launcher", Theme = "@style/MyTheme", MainLauncher = false, ConfigurationChanges = ConfigChanges.ScreenSize | ConfigChanges.Orientation, ScreenOrientation = ScreenOrientation.Portrait)]
        public class MainActivity : global::Xamarin.Forms.Platform.Android.FormsAppCompatActivity
        {
                protected override void OnCreate(Bundle bundle)
                {

                    base.OnCreate(bundle);

                    global::Xamarin.Forms.Forms.Init(this, bundle);         

                    LoadApplication(new App());
                }


            }

        }
```

**Home.cs**

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using Xamarin.Forms;

namespace Bakery
{
    public class Home : CustomTabPage
    {
        public Home()
        {

            NavigationPage.SetHasNavigationBar(this, false);

            var burger = new NavigationPage(new Burger());
            burger.Icon = "burger.png";
            burger.Title = "Burger";

            var sandwich = new NavigationPage(new Sandwich());
            sandwich.Icon = "sandwich.png";
            sandwich.Title = "Sandwich";

            var pizza = new NavigationPage(new Pizza());
            pizza.Icon = "pizza.png";
            pizza.Title = "Pizza";


            var roll = new NavigationPage(new Roll());
            roll.Icon = "roll.png";
            roll.Title = "Roll";

            //adding childrens into the tab
            Children.Clear();
            Children.Add(burger);
            Children.Add(sandwich);
            Children.Add(pizza);
            Children.Add(roll);
        }

        protected override void OnAppearing()
        {
            base.OnAppearing();     
        }
    }
}
```

**CustomTabPage.cs**

```
using System;
using Xamarin.Forms;

namespace Bakery
{
    public class CustomTabPage : TabbedPage
    {

    }
}
```

**styles.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<resources>
    <style name="MyTheme" parent="MyTheme.Base">
    </style>

    <style name="MyTheme.Base" parent="Theme.AppCompat.Light.DarkActionBar">

        <item name="windowNoTitle">true</item>

        <item name="windowActionBar">true</item>        

        <item name="windowActionModeOverlay">true</item>        


    </style>

</resources>
```

**CustomTabbedPageRenderer.cs**

```
 [assembly: ExportRenderer(typeof(TabbedPage), typeof(CustomTabbedPageRenderer))]
    namespace Bakery.Droid
    {
        public class CustomTabbedPageRenderer : TabbedRenderer
        {
            Activity activity;
            List<string> filenames;

            protected override void OnElementChanged(ElementChangedEventArgs<TabbedPage> e)
            {
                base.OnElementChanged(e);
                filenames = e.NewElement.Children.Select(t => t.Icon.File).ToList();
            }

            protected override void OnElementPropertyChanged(object sender, System.ComponentModel.PropertyChangedEventArgs e)
            {
                base.OnElementPropertyChanged(sender, e);
                activity = this.Context as Activity;
            }

            protected override void OnWindowVisibilityChanged(Android.Views.ViewStates visibility)
            {
                try
                {
                    base.OnWindowVisibilityChanged(visibility);
                    var actionBar = activity.ActionBar;
                    var colorDrawable = new ColorDrawable(Android.Graphics.Color.Yellow);
                    actionBar.SetStackedBackgroundDrawable(colorDrawable);
                    System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine("Onwindow visible");
                    ActionBarTabsSetup(actionBar);
                }
                catch (Exception Exception)
                {
                    System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine("Exception: " + Exception.ToString());
                }
            }

            void ActionBarTabsSetup(ActionBar actionBar)
            {
                for (var i = 0; i < actionBar.NavigationItemCount; ++i)
                {
                    var tab = actionBar.GetTabAt(i);
                    var id = GetImageFromFilename(i);
                    if (id != 0)
                        TabSetup(tab, id);
                }
            }

            void TabSetup(ActionBar.Tab tab, int resID)
            {
                var relLay = new Android.Widget.RelativeLayout(activity)
                {
                    LayoutParameters = new LayoutParams(LayoutParams.WrapContent, 180)

                };

                var linLay = new LinearLayout(activity)
                {
                    LayoutParameters = new LayoutParams(LayoutParams.WrapContent, 180),
                    Orientation = Orientation.Vertical,
                };
                linLay.SetHorizontalGravity(Android.Views.GravityFlags.Center);
                var imageView = new ImageView(activity);
                imageView.SetImageResource(resID);
                imageView.SetPadding(-35, 4, -35, 0);
                imageView.SetMinimumWidth(60);

                var textView = new TextView(activity)
                {
                    Text = tab.Text
                };


                linLay.AddView(imageView);
                linLay.AddView(textView);       

                relLay.AddView(linLay);

                var badgeView = new TextView(activity)
                {
                    Text = "2"
                };

                var badgeImageView = new ImageView(activity);
                badgeImageView.SetImageResource(Resource.Drawable.red);
                badgeImageView.SetMinimumWidth(5);
                badgeImageView.SetMinimumHeight(5);
                badgeImageView.SetPadding(77, 5, 0, 0);
                badgeView.SetPadding(85, 0, 0, 0);

                relLay.AddView(badgeImageView);
                relLay.AddView(badgeView);
                tab.SetCustomView(relLay);
            }

            int GetImageFromFilename(int n)
            {
                var filename = filenames[n].Split('.');
                var id = Resources.GetIdentifier(filename[0], "drawable", activity.PackageName);
                return id;
            }
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

> I am using the below code for showing a custom tab bar but it is always returning `null` value in `CustomTabbedPageRenderer.cs` class `OnWindowVisibilityChanged` method's `activity.ActionBar`.

The ActionBar is `null` because it is never set in the activity. You need to set the actionbar first:

1. In `MainActivity.cs` Set the SupportActionBar like below:

   ```
   //Create your own theme "MyTheme"
   [Activity(Label = "CustomTabbedPageDemo", Icon = "@drawable/icon", Theme = "@style/MyTheme", MainLauncher = true, ConfigurationChanges = ConfigChanges.ScreenSize | ConfigChanges.Orientation)]
   public class MainActivity : global::Xamarin.Forms.Platform.Android.FormsAppCompatActivity
   {
       protected override void OnCreate(Bundle bundle)
       {
           //Get the ActionBar Layout in Resouce\layout\Toolbar.axml
           var toolbar=(Toolbar)LayoutInflater.Inflate(Resource.Layout.Toolbar, null);
           //Set the Support ActionBar
           SetSupportActionBar(toolbar);
           SupportActionBar.Title = "My ActionBar";
           base.OnCreate(bundle);

           global::Xamarin.Forms.Forms.Init(this, bundle);
       LoadApplication(new App());
       }
   }
   ```
2. Create your own theme to replace the default one. `Xamarin.Forms` requires theme inherited from `Theme.AppCompat.XXX.XXX`:

   ```
   <style name="MyTheme" parent="Theme.AppCompat.Light.DarkActionBar">
       <item name="windowNoTitle">true</item>
       <item name="windowActionBar">false</item>
       <item name="colorPrimary">#5A8622</item>
   </style>
   ```
3. Basic `Toolbar.axml` example:

   ```
   <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
   <android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar 
       xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
       android:id="@+id/toolbar"
       android:layout_width="match_parent"
       android:layout_height="wrap_content"
       android:background="?attr/colorPrimary"
       android:theme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Dark.ActionBar"/>
   ```
4. Modify your `CustomTabPageRenderer.cs` change the namespace of `ActionBar` from `Android.App` to `using Android.Support.V7.App` and retrieve the `ActionBar` through `activity.SupportActionBar`:

   ```
   using Android.Support.V7.App;
   ...
   protected override void OnWindowVisibilityChanged(Android.Views.ViewStates visibility)
   {
       try
       {
           base.OnWindowVisibilityChanged(visibility);
           //get the support actionbar
           var actionBar = activity.SupportActionBar;

           var colorDrawable = new ColorDrawable(Android.Graphics.Color.Yellow);
           actionBar.SetStackedBackgroundDrawable(colorDrawable);
           System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine("Onwindow visible");

           ActionBarTabsSetup(actionBar);
       }
       catch (Exception Exception)
       {
           System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine("Exception: " + Exception.ToString());
       }
   }
   ```

Comment: Thanks @Elvis Xia - MSFT, I have changed the code as per your `suggestion` now I am getting value for `activity.SupportActionBar` but `activity.SupportActionBar.NavigationItemCount` is set with `0` even though `List<string> filenames` contains `4` items

Comment: You have defined your own `ActionBar`. It's a totally new `ActionBar`. So you need to add items to it yourself. The navigation options won't be added to it automatically.

Comment: Could you please provide any `sample` for adding `Tab Pages` which I am having in my *Home.cs* likely  `Burger.cs`,`Sandwich.cs`,`Pizza.cs`, `Roll.cs`